# Keep Silverlight DRY with UserControls

Tags: silverlight, dry

I have a `DataGrid` that is displaying some data at multiple points in my SL 4 app. I would like reduce redundancy. Is the correct way to do this by extracting it into a UserControl?

I did this. However, instead of setting `dataGrid.ItemsSource` in the code behind, I'm setting `myDataGridControl.ItemsSource`. However, `MyDataGridControl` doesn't have that property by default. Is there some way to forward those calls/properties to the `DataGrid`? Do I want to subclass `DataGrid` instead of containing it? Or is there another way to keep SL DRY?

Comment: What duplication are you trying to avoid: Xaml, Significant code or both?